# Finding overlapping attributes in two different layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, fields-attributes

I have two layers - one with country borders, and one with river basin borders - and I need to find a way to generate a list of basins that occur in each country.

Is there a way to find overlapping attributes (basins and countries) from two different layers using QGIS?

Comment: What type is your basin shapefile? Is it a line or a polygon?

Answer (score 7):

What you want to do is called a [Spatial Join](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php).

> A common GIS task is to join the attributes from one spatial data
>   layer to another. In this example we will join the attribute table
>   from a polygon layer to a points layer, based on which polygon
>   contains the points.

In QGIS, you can do that by using the **JOIN ATTRIBUTES BY LOCATION TOOL**.

[image]

You can then set your target and join vector layers.

[image]

I suggest that you set the river basins as the target vector layer and countries as the join layer. That way, your output would be a basins shapefile with the attributes of the countries shapefile. You could then generate your list from there.